# How to get the product list from magento 2 using Rest Api which is created within the specific time?

Tags: magento2

I want to get the products which is created within the specific time like from to time using Rest Api, please help..

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer which works fine,
http://localhost/magento2.0.4/rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2016-02-29%2017:12:00&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=from&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][value]=2017-10-29%2023:59:00&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][condition_type]=to

using two filters